# ember data not saving foreign key, sent as null

Tags: ember.js, foreign-keys, ember-data

My ember app is not sending my foreign key to the back-end.

I have a table called *issues* which is has a related table called *categories*

My model is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    category_id:    DS.belongsTo('category'),
    description:    DS.attr('string')
});
```

My route is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('issue');
  },
  actions: {
    create: function(){

        var issue = this.store.createRecord('issue');
        issue.name = this.get('controller').get('newName');
        issue.description = this.get('controller').get('newDescription');
        issue.category_id = parseInt(this.get('controller').get('newCategory'));
        //debugger;

        console.log(issue);
        issue.save();
    },
    ...
    other actions 
    ...
    }
  }
});
```

the console.log from above looks like the category_id is getting set correctly:

```
category_id: 3
description: "foobar"
name: "test"
```

However my JSON payload that gets sent to the backend looks like:

```
{"issue":{"name":"test","description":"foobar","category_id":null}}
```

I tried stepping through by adding a custom serialiser in app/serializers/application.js

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  ...

    serialize: function(snapshot,options){
      console.debug('options='+options);
      debugger;
      var json = this._super(snapshot, options);;

      return json;
    }
  ...
  });
```

But I got lost in all the super calling super indirection.

The *snapshot.record* has `category_id: 3`, but the *json* coming back from the this._super() call has `category_id: null`

*options* has `includeID:true`

Any clues will be much appreciated ...

Ember      : 2.0.2
Ember Data : 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition is wrong, when dealing with relationships you define them just as you would define any other attribute, there is no need to use `_id`.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    category:    DS.belongsTo('category'),
    description:    DS.attr('string')
});
```

As for the creation you should always use setters/getters when dealing with ember objects:

```
create: function() {
  var issue = this.store.createRecord('issue', {
    name: this.get('controller').get('newName'),
    description: this.get('controller').get('newDescription'),
    category: this.get('controller').get('newCategory') // assuming new category is a DS.Model instance of category
  });
  issue.save();
}
```

If you wish to stick to the syntax you have you would use `issue.set('name', this.get('controller').get('newName'))`, from the looks of your code it seems you are going about this in the wrong way.

You should have a `this.route('new')` nested under your issues route, that way you wouldn't have to use the controller to store information.

You would simply set the model of the new route to:

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.createRecord('issue');
}
```

Your template would make use of the [input helpers](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_input) like so:

`{{input value=model.name}}` and your action would just get the `currentModel` and call `.save()`.

Comment: I was using category (without _id) initially, but my backend API uses _id, which I add with `keyForRelationship` in the serializer, this works fine for retrieving records, but I wasn't sure if it was working for storing, so I was trying to check if that was causing the problem.

Comment: I have my inputs at the top of the index template which is supposed to allow the user to add new issues, I am not sure how to properly structure this, should I have an issue/index/new folder (I am using pods)

Comment: Is your backend by any chance rails?

Comment: backend is php lumen (laravel based)